# Finding indices of existing elements within a radius of a specific element

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a large matrix `A` and need to able to find the coordinates of all elements within a specific radius (`range`) of a given point `(xpos,ypos)`. The following is what I normally use for this:

```
    subx = max(1,xpos-range):min(n1,xpos+range);
    suby = max(1,ypos-range):min(n2,ypos+range);
    A_sub = A(subx,suby); %This is the submatrix around matrix A
```

where `n1` is `size(A,1)` and `n2` is the length of the matrix. The piece of code gives me the indices of all of the elements within the range. The problem I encounter occurs when point `(xpos,ypos)` is at the very edge of the matrix, such that `xpos-range` or `ypos-range` give me negative numbers (because it is giving the indices of elements or pixels that don't exist). Is there a way to modify this code so that I only get positive indices (indices of elements that actually exist)?

Comment: If "xpos-range" or "ypos-range" give you negative numbers doesn't your max expression result in a "1" which is a valid lower index into A?

Comment: I fail to see how the above code does not work too. Are you sure that a negative index is causing your issue?
Also, note that Matlab is column-major, i.e. the first dimension is a column. This means that it is easiest conceptually to associate `size(A,1)` with `y`, and `size(A,2)` with `x`.

Comment: "`n2` is the length of the matrix" Should this not be `n2=size(A,2)`?

Answer (score 1):

first, if you are using x,y notation, than `n1=size(A,2); n2=size(A,1)`.

second, use meshgrid to get all indices in both dimensions:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(subx,suby)

A_sub = A(X(:),Y(:));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a compact (not bothering with `size()`) way of writing this

set `xpos`, `ypos`, and `range`

and

```
A_sub = A(max(1,xpos-range):min(end,xpos+range),max(1,ypos-range):min(end,ypos+range))
```

should do the trick